# retrieve keycode when bound to 'input'

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
element.bind('keydown',function(e){
            console.log(e.keyCode); // returns the keycode
 }
```

This fails:

```
element.bind('input',function(e){
            console.log(e.keyCode); // returns undefined
 }
```

My simple question: Why the heck?

**Edit:**

a simple plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/OuWMsMp3lBD4gv8ccSFk?p=preview

Comment: what your calling input here?

Comment: input is not an event, how can you bind it?

Comment: @Bhushan: Of course [`input` is an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input)?!

Comment: i am using it successfully, so i guess it is one :o

Comment: ok. i did not know that. Thanks Bergi and Sprottenwels!

Comment: Here is a plnkr of the issue, i also added it in the question above http://plnkr.co/edit/OuWMsMp3lBD4gv8ccSFk?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because the [`input` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#event-input-input) is no [Keyboard Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboardevents). It works more like a `change` event, and is triggered by drag'n'drop, paste or other unusual *input* methods as well - not only when the user hits a key.

Comment: Thank you. May i ask where i could have found this information by myself, i have to admit that i was not able to get any clear answer by searching :/

Comment: First I looked [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input), where the `Interface` is given as the plain `Event` (in contrast to the [keyup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup) for example). Then I tried to find the relevant sections in the HTML(5) spec

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because the input event is fired after the text is already in the field, so the browser can't/won't detect what was entered.